# How to fix Tensorflow Error: Failed to create a NewWriteableFile

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new with tensorflow, I'm facing an issue while executing a [project](https://github.com/hcmlab/vadnet/blob/master/train/code/main.py) on window 10.

Using :
python-3.5.4
tensorboard-gpu=1.14.0
cuda-10

> ERROR:
>   tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Failed to create a NewWriteableFile: C:\Users\Reverie-PC\Desktop\tools\vadnet\train\nets\vad_Model[48000,48000,24000,512,None]_Conv7[2,True,False,4,2]_SceAdam[1e-04,0.9,0.999,1e-08]\ckpt\model.ckpt-0_temp_df1af0f684d24212bc1ebde45848fe3f/part-00000-of-00001.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate18107421248045726006 : The system cannot find the path specified.

path is correct and already created 
"nets\vad_Model[48000,48000,24000,512,None]_Conv7[2,True,False,4,2]_SceAdam[1e-04,0.9,0.999,1e-08]\ckpt" by script but "part-00000-of-00001.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate18107421248045726006" not creating.

I read somewhere, need to use an absolute path. I had tried that also but still facing the same error.
thank you!

Comment: You may be running into a [maximum path length limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). Could you check using a shorter path?

Comment: hi, i have already tried that, not working.

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: I've just solved my problem by shorting the path length of my file!

Comment: I met the save problem and i solved it by manually creating the folder  "model.ckpt-0_temp_df1af0f684d24212bc1ebde45848fe3f" under "ckpt" (just for your path).

Answer (score 0):

Fix the fix is ​​changing this value=1 to this property LongPathsEnabled:

[Solution Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTZ1f.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34675517)